# Importing packages from python 2.7 to 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I was using Python 3.7 on my Mac (version 10.12.6), even though my default is python 2.7. None of my import statements were working (import cv2, import Pyautogui) when I looked back and realized that I had downloaded the packages to python2.7. how do I reinstall or move these packages to 3.7, I'm hoping to make python 3.7 my primary module. if I could make them automatically go to 3.7 that would be great as well. I am required to use '--user' for may of my PIP statements so I don't know if you can use two '--' statements together. Thanks.

Comment: Python 2 and Python 3 are different languages.  Are you certain that the packages you want to install have support for Python 3?

Comment: keyboard,
time,
csv,
pyautogui,
cv2,
numpy,
PIL ,all of these have support for python 3.7

Answer (score 1):

If you have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed then you can access the PIP of Python 3 with the command `python3 -m pip install SomePackage`.

Please note, some packages might not be available for Python 3. Other packages might behave differently. Consider virtual environments like conda or venv for your work.

Comment: You are welcome. But it is highly recommended to use virtual environments like conda. While they look like a wast of time, you will save a lot of time once you can use them.